# Getting "URL Blocked" for Facebook login error on Rails 5 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm implementing Facebook login on a Rails 5 app with Devise and the `omniauth-facebook` gem and I'm getting the following error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

I followed this tutorial: https://medium.com/@trydelight/facebook-authentication-with-devise-5b53d2f664ed

So for the "Valid OAuth Redirect URIs" it works locally with no URIs whitelisted, but for production I added 
`https://noora.app/users/auth/facebook` and `https://www.noora.app//users/auth/facebook` (the production domain is `noora.app`). After getting the error I even added 2 more URIs with a `/` on the end and added `noora.app` and `www.noora.app` as domains, but I'm still getting the same error.

The app is on live mode and the login page is at `https://noora.app/users/sign_in`. Part of the Facebook settings are here:

[image]

Any ideas? Config seems good, but maybe someone sees something I don't? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should whitelist your callback url, not the one that has login button:
`https://noora.app/users/auth/facebook/callback`

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this answer for hours, the solution for me was:

When I checked the params in facebook error page, it said:

redirect=mydomain/auth/facebook/callback

and not:
redirect=mydomain/**users**/auth/facebook/callback

So I add the first one to Valid OAuth Redirect URIs, without users, and problem solved!!!